# Show HTML in jQuery and prevent broke webpage if it's invalid

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for library/jQuery Plugin/whatever to show HTML in div and prevents broking webpage. For example:

```
<div id="preview"></div>
<script>
    var foo = "<div>Bar<div>";
    $("#preview").html(foo);
</script>
```

In this example, HTML in `foo` variable is invalid and when I put it inside website, the document will be broken. How can I prevent it?

Comment: By not writing invalid HTML in the first place?

Comment: @Quentin HTML is typed dynamicly, by user. I can't do that.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/guguyugivo/1/edit?html,output — doesn't look very broken to me. (Obviously the HTML doesn't make sense, but by the time it's been through the jQuery parsing algorithms … what's the problem? Even if there was one (and there doesn't seem to be) it isn't like anyone is going to see the result other than the person who made the mistake)

Comment: Use a rich text editor like ckeditor if you're not sure if your users can write html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may write a simple function to map valid HTML from strings.

```
var checkIt = function(html) {
  var doc = document.createElement('div');
  doc.innerHTML = html;
  return ( doc.innerHTML === html );
}
checkIt("<div>Bar<div>"); //false
```

**Edit**

Using jQuery you may change the function to:

```
var checkHTML = function(html) {
  var $doc = jQuery(document.createElement('div'));
  $doc.html(html);
  return ( $doc.html()=== html );
}
```

Comment: And THIS is a real answer. Thanks :)

Comment: @Siper Cheers mate :)

Comment: This **does not work** — It tests to see if the inputted HTML is identical to *normalized HTML*, **not** if it is *valid*. —  See this test case where it claims some perfectly valid HTML is invalid: http://jsbin.com/motenalewe/1/edit?js,console or this test case where it claims some *invalid* HTML is valid: http://jsbin.com/vaxakehene/1/edit?js,console

Comment: @Quentin Actually this snippet check if the passed string is matched against the rendered DOM element. Your code on the first example is rendered and actually translated using lowercase tags, on the second one the tags are perfectly valid against Chrome's rendering mechanism. 
If you try to match both cases against IE's rendering engine you may notice different results.
One way or another the snippet above is a just a quick solution. A proper one would be testing the passed string using complex regular expressions.

Comment: "Your code on the first example is rendered and actually translated using lowercase tags" — That's my point. It gives false negatives.